# Dovecot plugin deleted_to_trash misses lib.h, make fails

Tags: c, linux, plugins, makefile, dovecot

I'm trying to install the Dovecot plugin [deleted_to_trash](https://github.com/lexbrugman/dovecot_deleted_to_trash). However, I need to update the configuration file, according to the readme, but I don't know what to fill in for `DOVECOT_INC_PATH`.

The directory that the author put, `/usr/include/dovecot`, doesn't exist.

If I try to `make` without changing anything, I get:

```
me@cs:/my-path/dtt# make
cc    \
          -fPIC -shared -Wall \
          -I/usr/include/dovecot \
          -I/usr/include/dovecot/src \
          -I/usr/include/dovecot/src/lib \
          -I/usr/include/dovecot/src/lib-storage \
          -I/usr/include/dovecot/src/lib-mail \
          -I/usr/include/dovecot/src/lib-imap \
          -I/usr/include/dovecot/src/lib-index \
          -DHAVE_CONFIG_H \
          src/deleted-to-trash-plugin.c -o lib_deleted_to_trash_plugin.so
In file included from src/deleted-to-trash-plugin.c:4:0:
src/deleted-to-trash-plugin.h:4:17: fatal error: lib.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [lib_deleted_to_trash_plugin.so] Error 1
```

I tried to find the missing `lib.h`, but nothing useful:

```
me@cs:/my-path/dtt# find / -name "lib.h"
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/include/config/rtc/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/include/config/iio/adis/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/include/config/snd/opl3/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/include/config/snd/firewire/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/include/config/snd/oxygen/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/include/config/snd/vx/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/include/config/ceph/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/include/config/x86/speedstep/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/include/config/rt2800/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic/include/config/rt2x00/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic/include/config/rtc/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic/include/config/iio/adis/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic/include/config/snd/opl3/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic/include/config/snd/firewire/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic/include/config/snd/oxygen/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic/include/config/snd/vx/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic/include/config/ceph/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic/include/config/x86/speedstep/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic/include/config/rt2800/lib.h
/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-35-generic/include/config/rt2x00/lib.h
```

**How can I find out the value I need for DOVECOT_INC_PATH**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to compile dovecot from source.
And I can find lib.h in dovecot-2.2.13.tar.gz from below url.

```
http://www.dovecot.org/releases/2.2/dovecot-2.2.13.tar.gz
```

If you installed dovecot as package, how about to install more dovecot related packages as like dovecot-dev or dovecot-source? I think you can find it.

If you can't resolve the problem, please copy lib.h file from sources tarball file to /usr/include/dovecot/src/lib.

Comment: Thank you - installing `dovecot-dev` and updating `DOVECOT_INC_PATH` to `/usr/include/dovecot` did the trick.